# Editing file in linux using bash

Tags: bash

say I have the following the text file :

```
.................
value1= "2000";
justAtext= "hello Text" 
..................................
```

my question is, is there any linux cmd that would allow me to search into the file for example for "value"
and than replace the whole line with something else like:

```
.................
changedText= "Hello";
justAtext= "hello Text" 
..................................
```

thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are several methods for doing it. The fastest IMO:

---

**input**

```
.................
value1= "2000";
justAtext= "hello Text" 
..................................
```

Assume this text is on a file named foo.txt

---

**elaboration**

`sed -iE 's/value1=.*/changedText= "Hello";/g' foo.txt`

- `-i` -> replace content on the same file (omitting this option the output will be printed on the Standard Output)
- `-E` -> use regex

---

**output**

```
.................
changedText= "Hello";
justAtext= "hello Text" 
..................................
```